# How to only match the string exclusively but not the words containing that string?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list

```py
a = ["CTC", "CTCglitches", "CTCremoval"]
```

I am running

```py
re.search("CTC", a[0]),....,re.search("CTC", a[2]).
```

I only want to return `True` for `re.search("CTC", a[0])`, and `False` for the remaining two words.

Is there any option in regex?

Comment: `"^CTC$"` should solve it for you ...

Comment: "CTC" in yourlist

Comment: If you want to know whether a string is exactly equal to some specific target string, why not just... compare them?

Answer (score 1):

Below code will work for you.
. We just need to use re.search("^CTC$", word)

```py
import re

a = ["CTC", "CTCglitches", "CTCremoval", "CTC test", "testCTC", "test CTC"]
for word in a:
    match = re.search("^CTC$", word)
    if match:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

Comment: This is wrong because it should not match `"CTC test"`.

Comment: It looks like you're using the same solution I did. The examples you provided don't demonstrate use of word boundaries in the regex.

Comment: Yeah this is wrong in accordance to the question.

Comment: Updated the answer. I think it will cover all scenarios. Thanks Karl for pointing out